# Why is grails.gorm.autoFlush set to true not working?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-3.0

Consider the following code:

```
class User {
    static constraints = {
        email email: true, unique: true
        token nullable: true
    }

    String email
    String password
    String token
}
```

---

```
@TestFor(User)
@TestMixin(DomainClassUnitTestMixin)
class UserSpec extends Specification {
    def "email should be unique"() {
        when: "twice same email"
        def user = new User(email: "test@test.com", password: "test")
        def user2 = new User(email: "test@test.com", password: "test")

        then: "saving should fail"
        user.save()
        !user2.save(failOnError: false)
    }
}
```

With the following configuration (part of it), application.yml:

```
grails:
    gorm:
        failOnError: true
        autoFlush: true
```

Why is `user2.save(failOnError: false)` not returning `false` due to it not being saved into the database?

Output of running: `grails test-app *UserSpec`:

> businesssoftware.UserSpec > email should be unique FAILED
>       org.spockframework.runtime.ConditionNotSatisfiedError at UserSpec.groovy:40

When I replace `user.save()` with `user.save(flush: true)` it *does* work.

However the documentation at https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/conf.html, Section 4.1.3 claims that:

> grails.gorm.autoFlush - If set to true, causes the merge, save and delete methods to flush the session, replacing the need to explicitly flush using save(flush: true).

For reference this is the output of `grails --version`:

> | Grails Version: 3.0.2
>     | Groovy Version: 2.4.3
>     | JVM Version: 1.8.0_40

And that's exactly what I am doing, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I think the autoFlush documentation is misleading.

> grails.gorm.autoFlush - If set to true, causes the merge, save and
>   delete methods to flush the session, replacing the need to explicitly
>   flush using save(flush: true).

Take a look at the save() methods and doSave() of [GormInstanceApi](https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/blob/8b0672e3e5047593037e556da111294acbcaf8af/grails-datastore-gorm/src/main/groovy/org/grails/datastore/gorm/GormInstanceApi.groovy). Toward the end of doSave() you'll see the session is only flushed when the flush parameter is true:

```
if (params?.flush) {
    session.flush()
}
```

There's nothing in the code suggesting that the flush parameter can come from any other place than what's passed to save().

I could not find the code to prove it, but I think autoFlush comes into play when the Hibernate session is closed, such as when a controller or service method exists/returns.

Also, the GORM implementation used for Spock and JUnit is not the *real* GORM, so it may not even use the autoFlush configuration.

I'm going to go on a limb here. I haven't tried this, but you *may* be able to flush the session manually.

```
@TestFor(User)
@TestMixin(DomainClassUnitTestMixin)
class UserSpec extends Specification {
    def "email should be unique"() {
        when: "twice same email"
        def user = new User(email: "test@test.com", password: "test")
        def user2 = new User(email: "test@test.com", password: "test")
        simpleDatastore.currentSession.flush()

        then: "saving should fail"
        user.save()
        !user2.save(failOnError: false)
    }
}
```

simpleDataStore comes from [DomainClassUnitTestMixin](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.3/api/grails/test/mixin/domain/DomainClassUnitTestMixin.html).